# How can I add a data source hosted Mapbox into a mapbox-gl-js project

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

How can I add a data source hosted Mapbox into a mapbox-gl-js project?
It used to be like this: http://bit.ly/1LcwekS way back in V.2.1

```
var sourceObj = new mapboxgl.Source({
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://foo-bar.ci58c127'
});
```

but mapboxgl.Source is no longer supported in mapboxgl.Source version 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new way to do this is via [Map#addSource](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map/addsource):

```
map.addSource('foo-bar.ci58c127', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://foo-bar.ci58c127'
});
```

The first argument is the source ID, which you can use when adding layers:

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "foo-bar.ci58c127",
    "layout": { ... },
    "paint": { ... }
});
```

Whenever there are breaking changes in a release, we add details about them in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), so if you come across any other upgrade issues that's the place to look. We're also planning to [pull that content directly into the API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1279).

Comment: Could you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975728/mapbox-and-tiff ? It looks related.