# MapBox and TIFF

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to show my TIFF file at the MapBox's map. I am starting with this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/ by replacing

```
map.addSource('terrain-data', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
});
```

with

```
map.addSource('terrain-data', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://xxx.yyy'
});
```

where `xxx.yyy` is my `Map ID` from Data section of the account (https://www.mapbox.com/studio/data/)

JavaScript initiates needed calls (to some `jpg` files), but all of them come with `404` error and the following message: `{"message":"Tile does not exist"}`

Answer (score 0):

If `xxx.yyy` is a tileset resulting from a TIFF upload, it's a [raster source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources-raster), not a vector source. You will need to replace `type: 'vector'` with `type: 'raster'`, specify `tileSize: 256`, and use it as the source for [raster layers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layers-raster).